# Terraform Conditionally out variable from a nested Conditional Module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I have a module such as this and need to output the variable of the module into another module

```
module "bucket" {
  source        = "../modules/storage_bucket"
    s3_list = {
    bucket_1 = {
      name               = bucket-1
      bucket_policy_only = false
      role_entity = [],
      lifecycle_rule = []
    },
    bucket_2 = {
      name               = bucket-2
      bucket_policy_only = false
      role_entity = [],
      lifecycle_rule = []
    },
    bucket_3 = {
      name               = bucket-3
      bucket_policy_only = false
      role_entity = [],
      lifecycle_rule = []
   },
    bucket_4 = {
      name               = bucket-4
      bucket_policy_only = false
      role_entity = [],
      lifecycle_rule = []
   },
    bucket_5 = {
      name               = bucket-5
      bucket_policy_only = false
      role_entity = [],
      lifecycle_rule = []
   }
```

The second module

```
module "bucket_func" {
  source              = "../modules/functions"
  func_1_name         = "${length(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name) > 0 ? lookup(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name, "func_1_name ", "") : null }"
  func_2_name         = "${length(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name) > 0 ? lookup(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name, "func_2_name ", "") : null }"
  func_5_name         = "${length(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name) > 0 ? lookup(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name, "func_5_name ", "") : null }"
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
 
   on main.tf line 164, in module "functions":
     func_1_name        = "$***length(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name) > 0 ? lookup(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name, "func_1_name", "") : null ***"

 module.bucket is a object, known only after apply
 
 This object does not have an attribute named "s3_list".
```

The code from the module `storage_bucket`:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage_bucket" {
  for_each = { for key, restr in var.s3_list : key => restr if restr.bucket_policy_only }
  name                        = each.value.name
  storage_class               = var.storage_class
  location                    = var.location
  force_destroy               = var.force_destroy
  uniform_bucket_level_access = each.value.bucket_policy_only
}
```

Comment: You have to define the proper output in the module `storage_bucket`.

Comment: @Marko E, will this output work
     
`
output "bucket" {
  value     = module.bucket.s3_list
  sensitive = true
}
`

Comment: No, please add the module code to the question, so I can provide an answer.

Comment: @MarkoE, The module code is module "bucket_func" as seem above, calling value from module "bucket"

Comment: I need to see what is inside of the `"../modules/storage_bucket"`.

Comment: @MarkoE, will this output work
    
 `
resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage_bucket" {
  for_each      = { for key, restr in var.s3_list :
                    key => restr if restr.bucket_policy_only
  }
  name          = each.value.name
  storage_class = var.storage_class
  location      = var.location
  force_destroy = var.force_destroy
  uniform_bucket_level_access = each.value.bucket_policy_only

  }`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with the code you are using:

1. You haven't defined output in the `storage_bucket` module
2. The `for_each` will not create anything, because the condition `if restr.bucket_policy_only` will never be `true` as all the `bucket_policy_only` values are set to `false`, so the output might not work even if defined
3. Even if the output was defined you cannot reference the value of a resource created with `for_each` using numbered keys (`0` in your example) unless the key is a number which it is not: `module.bucket.s3_list.0.name`

The output you would want to have (if the resource was created) would be:

```
output "s3_list" {
  value = values(google_storage_bucket.storage_bucket)[*].name
}
```

The `values` built-in function [1] will return a list of values, so the `length` function should work, however the value you are testing it for should change from:

```
"${length(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name) > 0 ? lookup(module.bucket.s3_list.0.name, "func_1_name ", "") : null }"
```

to

```
length(module.bucket.s3_list) > 0 ? contains(module.bucket.s3_list, "func_1_name") ? "func_1_name" : "" : null
```

This will as well always evaluate to `false` as none of the buckets have a name `func_*_name`, where the wildcard `*` replaces numbers `1`, `2` and `5`. So you would have either to:
a) name the buckets the same way, i.e., instead of `name = bucket-1` it should be set to `name = function_1_name` or
b) change the condition to check for `bucket-1`, `bucket-2` and `bucket-5`

Please make sure you understand how `for_each` [2] works, how lists [3] work and how to get values of the arguments and attributes for a resource [4].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/types

[4] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#resources